# BASH. Parsing blocks of text with additional conditions

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a task to upgrade nagios from version 2 to 4. There are several hundred files with deprecated tags. Here's one of them:

```
define host {
        use h-common1
        host_name a0
        address XX.XX.XX.XX
        check_command check-host-alive
        parents fw_ext
        }
define hostextinfo {
        host_name a0
        icon_image serv.jpg
        statusmap_image serv.jpg
       }
define service {
        use s-common1
        host_name a0
        service_description check_load
        check_command check_nrpe! check_load
        }

define service {
        use s-common1
        host_name a0
        service_description check-disks
        check_command check_nrpe! check_disk
        }
define service {
        use s-common1
        host_name a0
        service_description check_crond
        check_command check_nrpe! check_procs
        }
define service {
        use s-common1
        host_name a0
        service_description check_ntpd
        check_command check_nrpe! check_procs_1
        }
define service {
        use s-common1
        host_name a0
        max_check_attempts 1
        notification_options c, w
        service_description Find errors in logs
        check_command check_nrpe! check_logct
        }
```

**How do I delete all the rows with the tag "host_name", except that which is in the block "define host"?**
For example, i use this construction to delete all blocks "define hostextinfo":

```
for i in * ; do cat $i | sed -e '/}/r exceptions' -e '/^define hostextinfo{/,/}/d' > $i.tmp ; cat $i.tmp > $i; rm $i.tmp ;done
```

How can i modify this code for my case? I would be glad if I find the solution in one line.

Comment: What output do you expect ? For only the first block to be left in the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. All of it's constructs except s, g, and p (with -n) became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented, people just use them today for the mental exercise, not to actually create scripts they would use.

You didn't post your expected output so we're all guessing but is this what you want?

```
$ awk '$1=="define"{type=$2} !($1=="host_name" && type!="host")' file
define host {
        use h-common1
        host_name a0
        address XX.XX.XX.XX
        check_command check-host-alive
        parents fw_ext
        }
define hostextinfo {
        icon_image serv.jpg
        statusmap_image serv.jpg
       }
define service {
        use s-common1
        service_description check_load
        check_command check_nrpe! check_load
        }

define service {
        use s-common1
        service_description check-disks
        check_command check_nrpe! check_disk
        }
define service {
        use s-common1
        service_description check_crond
        check_command check_nrpe! check_procs
        }
define service {
        use s-common1
        service_description check_ntpd
        check_command check_nrpe! check_procs_1
        }
define service {
        use s-common1
        max_check_attempts 1
        notification_options c, w
        service_description Find errors in logs
        check_command check_nrpe! check_logct
        }
```

Normally I'd advise against a double negative but in this case I find the above easier to understand than the alternative if you remove the double negative:

```
awk '$1=="define"{type=$2} $1!="host_name" || type=="host"' file
```

Answer (score 4):

give this line a try:

```
awk '/^define host /{k=1}/[}]/{k=0}!k&&/host_name/{next}7' file
```

Comment: Nice one! Had something more complicated with awk in mind.

Comment: @123 you meant I misunderstood the question?

Comment: @123 why, from my understanding, it solves the problem, it removes all `host_name` lines except for `define host {...}`  block. If I misunderstood the requirement, pls correct me.

Comment: Also you don't need square brackets for the `}` awk can handle it fine without.

Answer (score 4):

With awk maybe?

```
/^define host / {print; h=1; next}
/^define/       {print; h=0; next}
/host_name/     {if (h) print; next}
                {print}
```

Comment: A little bit more complicated than Kent's answer but +1 for good readability. You may even add comments to the code to make it super-fancy.

Answer (score 0):

yet another `awk`

```
 awk '             /define/{del=1}  
       /define host/ || /}/{del=0} 
        /host_name/ && del {next} 1' recs
```